# Safari Web-Extensions - cannot save files using FileSaver.js

Tags: javascript, xcode, safari, filesaver.js, safari-web-extension

Safari stops the download(triggered from my browser extension) as soon as it begins and shows the file name as "**unknown**". I have figured out that this can also happen to any website if you set the **Download** permission for that website to **Deny** in the **Settings**.

Basically, my extension does not have permission to save files. But the issue is, Safari does not ask if I want to proceed with the download or not. It just stops the process.

How do I make Safari allow my extension to save files?